# Where to learn Esperanto?

Tags: learning

I think I understand the (quite easy) basic grammar now...
I just need some way to learn the words, but I don't just want to learn them off a list.
Some kind of text with each line in English and Esperanto would be perfect, so I learn it while reading...
Where do I find some material like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duolingo – Did you know that Duolingo has an Esperanto course? If you’re very busy, you can use this program to learn Esperanto from your smartphone in your downtime.

Lernu – This excellent website has three different Esperanto courses, depending on your learning style. I recommend you start with Ana Pana. The site also has live chat, an active forum, and the best Esperanto dictionary available.

Kurso de Esperanto – free downloadable program that teaches you the grammar of Esperanto from start to finish.

Answer (score 6):

*Classic fables* are freely available as e-books, leaving the English translation to childhood memories and an occasional dictionary lookup.

*Comics* have the same advantage of being readable without English translation at hand.

For real conversational language I agree with Oliver Mason in that course material like with [lernu.net](https://lernu.net/) are best. Such sites also provide some reading material.

Often *Esperanto clubs have bilingual periodicals*. Dictionary learning also works by that way.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [Duolingo](http://duolingo.com); this teaches you both words and grammar, translating in both directions.

Answer (score 5):

Each of [the exercises of the *Fundamento*](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/ekzercaro.html) includes a gloss. Although later exercises do expect you to already know the words from earlier exercises.

I personally found these exercises very helpful. Especially because they also demonstrate some nuances that aren’t covered in the grammar rules themselves.

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to the Fundamto language use, which is not only correct by definition, but also good.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I used the website lernu!, Now it looks different but I think it can be helpful.

https://lernu.net